# Getting list of References in VB.net programmatically

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way of getting all the References in a VB.NET (Community 2013) project and their paths, type, version, etc.?

There is something I found here on stackoverflow possibly related to this, but the Imports don't seem to be autocompleting to anything I've got:

Imports EnvDTE

Imports VSLangProj

[Reading the list of References from All csproj project of solution sln (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787116/reading-the-list-of-references-from-all-csproj-project-of-solution-sln-programm)

My ultimate goal is to look for a particular DLL and display the version.  I could also use GetFileVersionInfo(), if the version info isn't easy to extract.  I could, in theory, hardcode the file location of the DLL reference, but that seems not so elegant.

(A comment below mentioned that searching through the list wasn't elegant either, yes, of course!  Perhaps the question should be refined to the "I've got a known DLL that is loaded (Frogtown.dll); I don't know exactly where it might be on my system, but I know it is specified in the project.  Is there any way to get the DLL version, without knowing the full path?)

Addressing second comment:

To be clear, there is a living, breathing VB.NET application that is built with an external DLL (actually AForge.dll), and I'd like to know its version based on where it is stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework\Release (where I will install it on any machine that has the code, since a few applications may use those DLLs.   I am *not* writing a VB add-in.

There is a related question here (which I'm looking at through stackoverflow archives), in that there is a CopyLocal option in the project references section of the project. Currently, it is set to 'True', so that AForge.dll is copied to the local output directory, but I'm trying to set up the system so CopyLocal is set to 'False', and just reference it (where it lives in C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework\Release).

Right now, I get the version of the code by doing a call like:

GetFileVersionInfo(CurDir() & "\" & "AForge.dll")

Comment: and iterating all references looking for a specific one *does* seem elegant?  the link seems to be parsing solution files which seems to be something different than you are asking

Comment: Are you asking how to get this information from a DLL that is in the currently running vb.net application or are you writing an add-in for VS and you need this information for the current project/solution?