# Change AssemblyName in CSProj in code

Tags: c#, xpath, csproj

I'm writing a utility that will change the assembly name of a csproj file.  I know the csproj is essentially XML so XPath should work.  In fact, I can get it to work for certain information.  Here is the code I have:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(file);
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("x", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:PropertyGroup//AssemblyName", mgr);
node.Value = newValue;
xmlDoc.Save(file);
```

However, `node` is null.  I've also tried using `"//x:PropertyGroup[1]//AssemblyName"` to no avail.  If I just try and find `"//x:PropertyGroup"` it will work fine, so I'm assuming my issue is that not every PropertyGroup Node has an AssemblyName node.

I'm using a NamespaceManager per the suggestion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3745029/1265219) and I've been able to retrieve the AssemblyName value via XLinq as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1191151/1265219), but I need to update the value, not just read it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just guessing but wouldn't AssemblyName also be in the namespace denoted by x in this XPath: //x:PropertyGroup//AssemblyName. I.e. (without knowing the data) I bet it should be //x:PropertyGroup//x:AssemblyName

Comment: yeah, that was it.  Also, I can't just do `node.Value`, I need to do `node.FirstChild.Value`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is solved by comment:

Just guessing but wouldn't AssemblyName also be in the namespace denoted by x in this XPath: //x:PropertyGroup//AssemblyName. I.e. (without knowing the data) I bet it should be //x:PropertyGroup//x:AssemblyName – dkackman